# How to get the actual current working dir for a php cli script?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

~/worsh/worsh.php contains

```
print getcwd();
```

Now I do:

```
cd some-wordpress-site
php ~/worsh/worsh.php
```

And I get `~/worsh` - whereas I obviously want to just get `some-wordpress-site`.

`exec('pwd')` has the same result. How do I get what I want?

I should add that it works as expected on one of my hetzner boxes with php 5.3. It doesn't work on my bluehost account with php 5.2. I want it to work everywhere.

(See http://github.com/guaka/worsh for the use case.)

Comment: The result you're getting is absolutely correct, as this is the *current working dir* of your script. The directory `some-wordpress-site` is the current working dir of your shell program...

Comment: So, in other words you can't get what you want ;-)

Comment: But I do get what I want on another box with php 5.3...

Answer (score 0):

Check this related Post -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/17471242/1720166

Additionally check the corresponding PHP Function Doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

> ... getcwd() returns the path of the "main" script ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo __DIR__ ; //this is your directory path
```

the below should get you the last folder, which is what I think you want.
So if the path is `/var/www/html/some-wordpress-site` the below will return `some-wordpress-site`

```
echo basename(__DIR__);
```